# how to check valueOfKey is Array or Object when we get it from json in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have 2 cases to parse `JSON` First is:

```
{
    "post_filter_data": {
        "Items": [
            {
                "ItemID": "50cb4e46b5d30b0002000009",
                "ItemName": "Fruit salad test",
                "ItemPrice": "122.0",
                "ItemDescription": "test test",
                "ItemImageUrl": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/menubis-mms-prototype-dev/menubis/assets/50cb4e64b5d30b0002000013/landing_page.jpg?1355501156"
            },
            {
                "ItemID": "50d0870d910ef2000200000a",
                "ItemName": "test new",
                "ItemPrice": "120.0",
                "ItemDescription": null,
                "ItemImageUrl": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/menubis-mms-prototype-dev/menubis/assets/50d0871a910ef20002000015/Screenshot-2.png?1355843354"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

in which Items is an `NSArray` and it's parse easily but when only one object I get its through exception.
Second `JSON` is in which Items tag has one one object:

```
{
    "post_filter_data": {
        "Items": {
            "ItemID": "50d1e9cd9cfbd20002000016",
            "ItemName": "test",
            "ItemPrice": "120.0",
            "ItemDescription": "test",
            "ItemImageUrl": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/menubis-mms-prototype-dev/menubis/assets/50d1ea019cfbd20002000022/11949941671787360471rightarrow.svg.med.png?1355934209"
        }
    }
}
```

and my code is here In which I am parsing it:

```
NSDictionary *dictMenu=[responseDict valueForKey:@"post_filter_data"];
NSArray* subMenuArray=[dictMenu valueForKey:@"Items"];
```

Is there any way in which I check it out that `valueForKey:@"Items"` is `Array` or `Object`.

Comment: where are you getting this json from? do you have controll over it? i would consider changing the json itself to always send an array, even with one object in it.  of course you can check the type as the answers below describe how..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get data rx in _recievedData then check the class of the object.

```
    id object = [NSJSONSerialization
                     JSONObjectWithData:_recievedData
                     options:kNilOptions
                     error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
         NSLog(@"Error in rx data:%@",[error description]);
    }
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == YES)
    {
         NSLog(@"String rx from server");
    }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == YES)
    {
         NSLog(@"Dictionary rx from server");
    }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] == YES)
    {
         NSLog(@"Array rx from server");
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can check using `class` like

```
if ([[dictMenu valueForKey:@"Items"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    // array inside
}
```