# objectForKey throws an exception on count if it contains a single value

Tags: ios, json

I have a dictionary JSON dictionary like

```
{
  county = "XXXXX";
  states =             (
       "YYYYY",
       "ZZZZZ"
  );
}
```

After reading the JSON dictionary the data is in an array. I then want to create a different array with the data and I am using the following code

```
for (NSString *key in array) {
      NSMutableArray *myData =[[NSMutableArray aalloc] init];
      myData = [array objectForKey:key];
      int count = [myData count];
}
```

When key is 'states', it works fine. If key is 'country', then it throws an exception on count because objectForKey returns a NSString. How to resolve this? How to find how many objects the objectForKey will return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out this answer from @HDdeveloper:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968627/1671729)

```
if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == YES)
{
     NSLog(@"String rx from server");
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == YES)
{
     NSLog(@"Dictionary rx from server");
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] == YES)
{
     NSLog(@"Array rx from server");
}
```

Basically, after you get the `objectForKey`, then you need to check what kind of object that is and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON contains a dictionary.

The key "states" in that dict  contains an array, and the other key contains a string. Neither key contains an NSData object.

Arrays have a count method, but strings do not. That's why you're crashing.