# How to get value from JSON Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

May I know how to get respond value from JSON in below code format? Currently I'm using this way, but it won't work for me

What I use to get JSON value:

```
NSError * err2 = nil;
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                options:0
                                                  error:&err2];

NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

The JSON value that I wanted to get:

```
 [
          {
            "Status": 1,
            "NearuCode": "17060521957",
            "ParcelBox": "Thursday"
          },
          {
            "Status": 1,
            "NearuCode": "17060521957",
            "ParcelBox": "Thursday"
          }
        ]
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @dahiya_boy the respond does not display me the JSON value that I want

Comment: @Edmund how are you retreiving the value?

Comment: Which array does not give the response?

Comment: print the json and jsonObject array results

Comment: @user3182143 the below code "The JSON value that I wanted to get:"

Comment: What is the output of json and jsoonObject?

Comment: @user3182143 It return empty array

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968397/how-to-check-valueofkey-is-array-or-object-when-we-get-it-from-json-in-ios

Comment: Do both they give empty results?

Comment: @user3182143 yes, both also empty

Comment: Then show me your full code for getting response

Comment: I will help you.Show your full code.

Comment: I want you to show full code with url and parameter

Comment: @user3182143 I think I solved the issues using mike given solution

Comment: But it gives you the empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you the solution which explains you the description of error as you get empty results.

```
NSError * err2 = nil;
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                            options:0
                                              error:&err2];
if (err2)
{
     NSLog(@"The reason for the error is - %@",[err2 description]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome brother

Answer (score 2):

Your `JSON` response is `Array` not `Dictionary` also in your response both the object in array are having the same data.

```
NSMutableArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonObject) {
     NSLog(@"%@", dic[@"Status"])
     NSLog(@"%@", dic[@"NearuCode"])
     NSLog(@"%@", dic[@"ParcelBox"])
}
```

Comment: a json can be array or dictionary so you can't just only assign it to array this might work for this answer only though better put it to id object and ten check its type

Comment: @hariszaman Don't you think JSON that coming from API will stay fix will not changed if it is array it will stay array on iOS side also. If JSON is already known why should be use id instead of its specific type

Comment: what if he uses the same code for API that doesn't returns array?

Comment: @hariszaman Have you read the question, OP already added its JSON response and also I have mentioned in my answer then your `JSON` response is `array` not `dictionary`.

Comment: First of all op does not get the response.He gets empty results.

Comment: @NiravD what I am saying that the code should be generic enough to parse json whether the json is an array or a dictionary. Lets say he is using multiple APIs in his app some of them returning arrays and other return dictionary. will the above code work for all those?

Comment: @hariszaman How you are going to handle it with generic does all array response having same dictionary key or does all dictionary response having same key, **No** that means you need to know what your response it is you need to handle on the basis of it

Comment: cast it to id and then check its type.

id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
if([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
    //Is array
}else if([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    //is dictionary
}else{
    //is something else
}

Comment: @hariszaman And then what? This type of thing necessary when your response type will known at run time not here, no need to add this comparison code if you already known the JSON response.

Comment: this code it not going to work when the reponse is not array.. and then you have a code that will work when your response is array or dictionary which one is better?

Comment: @hariszaman You handle the response like this if you already know your response, if you are doing like that you are making too much unnecessary code.

Comment: more code is better than a crash that can be caused by casting dictionary to array and accessing that array(if response is dictionary). Moreover the code should be generic enough.